# CMake error: not able to compile simple test program

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, caffe

After changing my env to Python 2.7, I got this error after running build_win.cmd

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/deVam/Anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/Library/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/caffe/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/deVam/Anaconda3/envs/pythonenv/Library/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_b499f && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_b499f.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_b499f.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_b499f.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\deVam\Anaconda3\envs\pythonenv\Library\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b499f.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_b499f.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_b499f.exe /implib:cmTC_b499f.lib /pdb:cmTC_b499f.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_b499f.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_b499f.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (project)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are you trying to build? Please provide code or a link to an open-source repository for the code you are trying to build. Please provide the *complete* command you are using to produce this error.

Comment: actually i am just getting through caffe installation ..i am using this link for instructions "https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows" i am using python interface..firstky , I run this, conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels willyd then this conda install --yes cmake ninja numpy scipy protobuf==3.1.0 six scikit-image pyyaml pydotplus graphviz"...after that git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git and checkout for windows and finally build_win.cmd and got this error